# How to use PHP Mail function or sendmail to send and/or receive emails from my live site

Tags: 7, emails

I am hosting my site on OVH and they have told me that sending emails using external SMTP servers is not allowed. I need to use the PHP Mail function or sendmail. I have a Drupal 7 installation and I am completely lost.

- Which of these is the best option?
- What steps do I need to follow in order to use one of these options?

My site is currently live and I am not able to receive emails through my contact form.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is that a typo? do you mean you are not able to SEND emails through the contact form?

Comment: If so, Drupal uses php mail() by default - so unless you have altered that behaviour, it should work if your host supports php mail() as per (https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21mail.inc/function/drupal_mail_system/7)

Comment: I haven't altered any behaviour. I have used the SMTP Authentication support module and the PHP Mailer module. I have configured them in the appropriate way and I get them to work from localhost. However, I cannot get them to work on the live site. They have told me that using external SMTP servers is not allowed and that I only have the two options mentioned above. Why don't those modules work? How can I get the emails to work without using those modules?

Comment: SEND isn't a typo. If somebody fills in the contact form it gives them an error and I do not receive any emails.

Comment: The default contact form uses php Mail(), so in fact you ARE altering that behaviour by using the SMTP Authentication support module, which clearly states "This module allows Drupal to bypass the PHP mail() function and send email directly to an SMTP server." which you have indicated is prohibited by your host.

Comment: ok, I am very ignorant about this subject. I thought I needed to make changes myself. So, do you think I will be able to get it to work using the PHPMailer module? or do I need to do something else?

Comment: what is the purpose of using those modules? as apposed to using the default drupal mailer? If there isn't a reason, the default behaviour should work for you just fine, without the intrusion of extra modules...

Comment: I though I needed to configure something in order to get my email to work. Ok, I'm going to try it out without any modules.

Comment: no module required! Drupal comes ready to go with everything you need for contact forms.  There are modules you can get to customise and control multiple variations of contact forms, but the underlying functionality is already there...

Comment: It works fine. I was ill advised by someone that I needed to use a module for emails on Drupal. Thank you very much for your help. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments above:

Since your server does not permit direct SMTP communication, and since SMTP Authentication Support specifically overrides the default behaviour "This module allows Drupal to bypass the PHP mail() function and send email directly to an SMTP server."

I would suggest disabling the two modules, SMTP Authentication support and PHPMailer, and use the default drupal mailer which by default uses php mail() as permitted by the server.

Answer (score 0):

If you use [Drupal PHPmailer](https://www.drupal.org/project/phpmailer) it would work like a charm, just set your gmail account info. and It would work.